# Disable network drive error message on other networks

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-drive

On my laptop (Windows 10 Pro), I connect to a network drive (Z) at work, which is **only** available on our local network.

When I take my laptop home, inevitable leaving several windows of File Explorer open to different parts of the Z: drive, I'm bombarded with a load of error messages saying `An error occurred while reconnecting Z:\ to...`

Is there a way to either:

- Suppress those messages while not on my work network (so I can still
  tell if there is any sort of server error while at work)
- Suppress those messages all the time

Answer (score 3):

A simple registry change (from [technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/265fd82d-66a7-44a3-aa38-6313a19ae8b7/disable-could-not-reconnect-all-network-drives-messageicon-in-domain-environment?forum=win10itpronetworking)) will fix this:

On:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\
```

Set or create a DWORD: `RestoreConnection`. Set its value to 0.

The popup messages will be supressed **forever** this way.

I couldn't find a way to supress the error only outside of the work network but this will do the trick.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but do you have a reference source for this answer?

Comment: @Run5k sure, forgot to mention, thanks for the advice!

Comment: I'm not used to working in the registry. Just to clarify, the entry name should be RestoreConnection and the value (hex) should be 0?

Comment: @Octavian yeah, that's it.

Comment: @Octavian If my answer solved your problem, please accept it if you feel appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to be working. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Octavian Found other [possible solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1a60e163-5a0e-453e-be31-c60abe12471b/disable-network-notifications-for-reconnect-all-network-drives?forum=w7itpronetworking).

Comment: @Octavian Going with the information in this answer, I'm not sure where you got (hex) from. You should be creating a DWORD named "RestoreConnection" and then set its value to "0"